# Can you summon an Elemental Myrmidon, and if so, do you need the armor?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, summoning

If I cast Conjure Elemental at a higher level, could I summon an Elemental Myrmidon? Also, it says they are summoned into armor, empowering them, so would you need some armor to summon one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes, you can summon it. No, you do not need armor.**

The Conjure Elemental Spell says that you can summon an elemental of CR 5 or lower. In the 'At Higher Levels' section, it says that the CR of the monster increases by one for each higher level spell slot you use.

Using a 7th level spell slot to cast Conjure Elemental would allow you to summon an elemental of CR 7. It is my understanding that the Elemental Myrmidons are CR 7, so it would be possible to summon one using this spell.

You would not need special armor for the summoning, as the spell description makes no mention of additional components beyond those listed.

Answer (score 10):

As the spell is written, any creature of the type "elemental" and the correct level is valid, and would appear as described in the stat block of that creature. Therefore, the rules say that you can do this, and the armor would come with it. This could possibly suppose that the myrmidon had previously been created and given its armor, gone back to it's home plane with the armor and was then summoned by you.

However, it has been clarified by the developers that the DM, not the player, chooses the exact creature that appears. A DM would be well within their rights to never choose a myrmidon based on the flavor text requirements regarding armor.

So, yes, it is possible, but only if your DM wants it to.